# Properties for Search Service Error

Tags: 2013, search, service

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and have provisioned the services I need successfully. I've setup Search Service also successfully and it is functioning properly. However, when I go into Service Applications and try to view the properties I get the following:

Sorry, something went wrong

> An unhandled exception occurred in the user interface.Exception Information: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.
>   Technical Details*

---

Looked at my ULS logs and this is what gets logged:

> Unhandled page level exception. Path: /_admin/search/TopologyAppSettings.aspx, Error: Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration., Details: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration. at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Session() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchConfigWizardBase.OnInit(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration. at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Session() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchConfigWizardBase.OnInit(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) StackTrace: at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=678c0f87-966f-4d99-9c94-b49e788d2672|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=131CE) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21BE5)

I also get something similar to this error when I view the properties for **BDC, Secure Store Service and Visio Graphics Services.** any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open powershell and make sure Session State Service is active

```
Get-SPSessionStateService
```

Then enable it using

```
Enable-SPSessionStateService –DefaultProvision
```

Check web configuration files and make sure following entry is present

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
```

Another work around is to Disable and then Enable using following script

```
Disable-SPSessionStateService
Enable-SpSessionStateService -DatabaseName SP_SessionState
```

Change the `DatabaseName` as per your standards.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I had to add <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" /> to my web.config file as it was not present even after the reprovisioning.